# Python packaging - package not found

Tags: python

I'm using the following python project structure in order to allow packaging (based on [this](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html)):

[image]

In each package I import all the submodules using

```
__init__.py
```

When i'm inside config.py and trying to

```
import settings
```

it does not identify settings as a package of modules..

How should I refer to that so it will recognise it?

Comment: have you tried `from settings.settings import settings`?

Comment: actually now that i'm testing it, I see that it does recognise the package, it is something with the PyCharm IDE that doesn't recognise settings as a package to import

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that because everything was inside as_manager package, I should have `import as_manager.settings` ...